# Can not create LDAP connection-Nexus repository

Tags: ldap, nexus

I want to create a LDAP authentication for my OSS Nexus repository.

I use below info

Protocol : ldap

Authentication method : DIGEST-MD5

But When I create a LDAP connection in Nexus OSS it getting below error

Failed to connect to LDAP Server: a.b.c.d:636; socket closed

connectivity from My repository to LDAP server is OK.

What is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the ldap works on port 389 and it operates on 636 for ldaps. you might need to add the certificates you can do:`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.com:369`.This command will give you pem's you can copy and paste it through ui to ssl certificates.